# How do I pick specific elements out of a JSON file and display them in an HTML table? in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

I am trying to make a call to a JSON file and extract the elements and place them in an HTML table. At the moment I have managed to do that by making the call and place the contents in the JSON File in an array then looping through the array and placing them in an HTML table that I have created dynamically. I would like to be able to choose specific elements in the JSON file and not display all of them in the table.

I hope this makes sense, here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("my url", function (data) {

        var jsonData = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            jsonData.push(value);

        });


        // Header for table 
        var tblColumn = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            for (var key in jsonData[i]) {
                if (tblColumn.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    tblColumn.push(key);
                }
            }
        }



        //Dynamic Table

        var table = document.createElement("table");

        //create table row

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var i = 0; j < tblColumn.length; j++) {

            var tblCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tblCell.innerHTML = tblColumn[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < tblColumn.length; j++) {
                var tblCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tblCell.innerHTML = jsonData[i][tblColumn[j]];

            }
        }

        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    });
```

This is my HTML code:

```
 <button id="test" type="button">Get request</button>
            <div id="showData">

            </div>
```

UPDATE: Sample JSON File:

```
[
 {
"Id": 0,
"ProcessingDate": "2017-08-01T13:08:00.967Z",
"Filename": "string",
"BatchDescription": "string",
"Status": "string",
"UploadedById": 0,
"UploadedByName": "string",
"AuthorisedById": 0,
"AuthorsiedByName": "string",
"UploadedDate": "2017-08-01T13:08:00.967Z",
"ConfirmedDate": "2017-08-01T13:08:00.967Z",
"AuthorisedDate": "2017-08-01T13:08:00.967Z"
 }
]
```

Would really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: adding sample JSON would help....

Comment: Sorry about that will update now @Ashish451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at your code and understand what your doing but when I do these kind of things I normally build the table so that I can style it and add a message like "Loading Data" when its loading then when the data is ready it gets added. This just makes it a little nicer for the user instead of a table appearing out of no where ;)

I made this example in a way so its easy to add new columns to your table in the future by making it so you just need to add to the `fields` array and add columns to the table head.

```
<!-- Button to request data -->
<button id="reqBtn">Request Data</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!--
            Add a column header for each field
            you want to display In this example
            it will display the ID, Filename,
            Status and UploadedDate
            -->

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Filename</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Upload Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="rows"></tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
        In order you want them to display add
        the field name into this array

        In this example it will display the
        ID, Filename, Status and UploadedDate
     */
    var fields = [
        "Id",
        "Filename",
        "Status",
        "UploadedDate"
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#reqBtn").click(function () { // When the request button is clicked

             // Request the JSON data
             $.getJSON("URL_TO_FILE", function (data) {

                 // Create a variable to hold all the rows
                 var rows = "";

                 // For each object in the JSON data
                 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                     // Add a new table row tag to the rows variable
                     rows += "<tr>";

                     // For all the fields you want to display
                     for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                         // Add the value to the row
                         rows += "<td>" + value[fields[i]] + "</td>";
                     }
                     // End the row tag
                     rows += "</tr>";
                 });

                 // Add the rows to the table body
                 $("#rows").html(rows);

             });
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Really helped !

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answered if it answered your question.